# How to add a virtual primary monitor in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, display, gpu, teamviewer, steam

So I have this problem: my PC running latest Windows 10 doesn't have a monitor, and it causes **some GPU-accelerated applications and games to give blank or whitescreen output.**

The cause is well-known: **GPU doesn't see a monitor in some cases, and thus doesn't output anything.** Since remote control software like *TeamViewer* and *Steam in-house streaming* simply capture the output, they will also get a whitescreen output (see image below).

To combat this issue, one solution is to add a fake primary monitor. **There are solutions using HDMI adapters. But I want to find a software solution.**

To make things worse, [Windows 10 used to have a way to add VGA display manually](https://superuser.com/questions/947291/can-a-fake-second-display-be-enabled-in-windows-10), but they have removed this ability in recent updates.

**Does anyone have some idea on how to add a virtual primary monitor for Windows 10 in 2017 (now soon 2018)?**

Thx!

[image]

Comment: I am not talking about [virtual desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/965385/assigning-a-virtual-desktop-to-a-monitor-in-windows-10) by the way.

Comment: Ended up buying a HDMI dummy plug. It does work though. https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DSXqTccUIAUm5R2.jpg:orig