# I'm trying to get two different virtual desktops on two different monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I'm trying to get two different virtual desktops on two different monitors, when I right click one of them, it doesn't show up with the options of "Show windows from this app on all desktops"

How do I do this with Windows 10? version 20H2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning a virtual desktop to a monitor in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/965385/assigning-a-virtual-desktop-to-a-monitor-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

While this would be an awesome feature (apparently Mac has something that works like this called Spaces), there is not a built-in way to do this, but [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1299300/1025486) contains a workaround.