# How do I disable desktop switching on my external monitor?

Tags: windows-10

I recently went and got an external monitor to connect to my laptop and found that when I try to switch screen(aka switching between virtual desktops) on my laptop, it also switches screen on my external monitor. Is there any way to either:

1. Disable screen/desktop switching on my external monitor but not my internal monitor

or:

2. Such that desktops are independent of each other. Aka: I can switch screen on my laptop without affecting my current screen on external monitor and I can switch screen on my external monitor without affecting my current screen on laptop. (Preferable)

Edit: [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/965385/assigning-a-virtual-desktop-to-a-monitor-in-windows-10) did help me pin down one virtual desktop on my external monitor, but when I switch screen on my laptop, the screen on the external monitor still moves, which is a bit annoying after some time. AKA I wanted for the external monitor desktop to be fixed in place, not just copying that desktop over all other virtual desktops. I see that the question was answered almost 6 years ago, maybe there is a more modern solution created since then?

Comment: What does "switch screen" mean here? Are you talking about virtual desktops?

Comment: @gronostaj Yes that's what I meant.

Comment: @CipherBot - [Edit] your question and clarify what you meant.

Comment: @Ramhound Added a note in.

Comment: While a virtual desktop will change all monitors, if there is a specific window or application you wish to maintain you can have it show on all desktops. The answer is at the related question here: [Assigning a virtual desktop to a monitor in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/965385/assigning-a-virtual-desktop-to-a-monitor-in-windows-10/1299300#1299300)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning a virtual desktop to a monitor in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/965385/assigning-a-virtual-desktop-to-a-monitor-in-windows-10)

Comment: @Toto, Thanks for the suggestion, it did help to pin down one virtual desktop on my external monitor, but when I switch screen on my laptop, the screen on the external monitor also moves, which is a bit annoying after some time. AKA I wanted for the external monitor desktop to be fixed in place, not just copying that desktop over all other virtual desktops. I see that the question was answered almost 6 years ago, maybe there is a more modern solution created since then?